# Css image on left of centered text

Tags: html, css

I try to display an image on left of a centered text ! But the only thing i did is to center the image + text ! i want only the text to be centered horizontally and then image on his left and both centered vertically

```
<div id="the-block"><div class="titleproduct" style="text-align: center;"><img itemprop="image" src="large.png" id="theimage" alt=""align="middle">BLablaba</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the command

```
Float: left;
```

Dont you use a stylesheet.css or something? I recommend to use that, So you dont have to do the style in the html file but in a extendent file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="the-block">
        <div class="titleproduct" style="text-align: center;">
             <p>Some text...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="image" style="float:left">
             <img itemprop="image" src="large.png" id="theimage" alt=""align="middle">BLablaba
        </div>

   </div>
```

you can try this one

Answer (score 0):

I created a example for you...but for that you must need the image height value.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.titleproduct {
  position: relative;
  top: 75px; /* Just half of image height */
}

img#theimage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}

div#the-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="the-block">
  <div class="titleproduct" style="text-align: center;"><img itemprop="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" id="theimage" alt="" align="middle">
    <p>BLablaba</p>
  </div>
</div>
```